# actuator metrics tag PathVariable and wildcard

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using spring boot 2 actuator metrics to statistics API requests. But I face some issues, and I don't find so much relevant document.

> Total number of requests resulted in a 4xx response
>
> Total number of requests resulted in a 5xx response

1,

I can use http://localhost:8080/travel/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=status:400
to get status 400 info, but I'd like to know is there any method to wildcard 4xx request? or I have to loop all 4xx status codes one by one in my codes?

2,

```
  @GetMapping("/{type}/{code}")
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<Location>> getLocationByTypeAndCode(
  @NotNull @PathVariable("type") final String type,
  @NotNull @PathVariable("code") final String code) {
```

I use PathVariable parameters in my controller, but when I use 
http://localhost:8080/travel/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/locations/{type}/{code}

I got 400 bad request error

I'm new to Spring Boot Actuator, Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

1: To get all the 4xx errors you can use: `?tag=outcome:CLIENT_ERROR`.

2: The brackets need to be URL encoded: `?tag=uri:/locations/%7Btype%7D/%7Bcode%7D`